# Issue with Java Guessing Game

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I'm working on this guessing game for school. I've realized that at some point I deleted my while loop for the user's guess equalling the computer's random number and it has messed up the results of my program. I thought that I could just add a nested while loop, but that hasn't worked. I've been trying to figure this out for hours.

Any ideas how to add something like while (guess == number) to my code and keep it working?

```
/*
Programming Assignment #3: Guess
Peter Harmazinski 
Week 8

Guessing Game
*/

import java.util.*;

public class Guess {           
   public static final int RANGE = 100;       

   public static void main(String[] args) {  
      Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
      boolean again = true;
      double guessesDividedByGames = 0;
      int maxGuesses = 0;
      int numGames = 0;
      int numGuesses = 1;
      int totalGuesses = 0;
      Random rand = new Random();
      int number = rand.nextInt(RANGE) + 1;
      int guessTracker = 0;

      while(again) {
         getInstructions(); 
         int guess = getGuess(console);
         numGuesses = getHigherLower(guess, number, console);
         totalGuesses += numGuesses;
         again = playAgain(numGuesses, console);
         numGames++;  
         if (numGuesses > maxGuesses) {
             maxGuesses = numGuesses;
         }    
      }

      guessesDividedByGames = (double)totalGuesses / numGames;
      getResults(numGames, totalGuesses, guessesDividedByGames, maxGuesses);
   }


   //Prints instructions for user
   public static void getInstructions() {
      System.out.println("This program allows you to play a guessing game");
      System.out.println("I will think of a number between 1 and " + RANGE);
      System.out.println("and will allow you to guess until you get it.");
      System.out.println("For each guess, I will tell you whether the");
      System.out.println("right answer is higher or lower than your guess");
      System.out.println("");
   }

   //Allows the user to play again if first letter of input is "y" or "Y"
   public static boolean playAgain(int guessesNum, Scanner console) {
      boolean anotherTime = false;
      System.out.println("You got it right in " + guessesNum + " guesses.");
      System.out.println("");
      System.out.print("Do you want to play again? ");
      String repeat = console.next();
      String[] yesOrNo = repeat.split("");
      System.out.println("");
      if (yesOrNo[0].equals("y") || yesOrNo[0].equals("Y")) {
         anotherTime = true;
      }
      return anotherTime;
   }

   //Outputs the results if the user doesn't play again
   public static void getResults(int gamesTotal, int guessesTotal, double guessesDividedByGames, int guessesMax) {
      System.out.println("Overall results:");
      System.out.println("\ttotal games\t= " + gamesTotal);
      System.out.println("\ttotal guesses\t= " + guessesTotal);
      System.out.println("\tguesses/game\t= " + guessesDividedByGames);
      System.out.println("\tmax guesses\t= " + guessesMax);   
   }

   //Tells the user whether the random number is higher or lower
   //and then returns the number of guesses
   public static int getHigherLower(int guess, int randomNumber, Scanner console) {
      int guessIncreaser = 1;
      while (guess > randomNumber) {
         System.out.println("lower");
         guess = getGuess(console);
         guessIncreaser++;
      }
      while (guess < randomNumber) {
         System.out.println("higher");
         guess = getGuess(console);
         guessIncreaser++;
      }
      return guessIncreaser;
   }

   //Asks the user to guess the random number 
   //then returns the guess
   public static int getGuess(Scanner console) {
      System.out.println("I'm thinking of a number...");
      System.out.print("Your Guess? ");
      int playerGuess = console.nextInt();
      while (playerGuess < 1 || playerGuess > RANGE) {
         System.out.println("Out of range, please try again.");
         System.out.print("Your Guess? ");
         playerGuess = console.nextInt();
      }
      return playerGuess;
   }
}
```

Comment: Don't you mean `while (guess != number)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem appears to be your `getHigherLower` method, specifically these two while blocks:

```
  while (guess > randomNumber) {
     System.out.println("lower");
     guess = getGuess(console);
     guessIncreaser++;
  }
  while (guess < randomNumber) {
     System.out.println("higher");
     guess = getGuess(console);
     guessIncreaser++;
  }
```

If the user guessed a number lower than `randomNumber`, then higher, both `while` blocks would be escaped. Instead, what you want is this:

```
while (guess != randomNumber) {
    if (guess > randomNumber) {
        System.out.println("lower");
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("higher");
    }
    guess = getGuess(console);
    guessIncreaser++;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need is one big while loop not two little ones

```
while (guess != randomNumber) {
    if (guess > randomNumber) {
       System.out.println("lower");
    } else {
       System.out.println("higher");
    }
    guess = getGuess(console);
    guessIncreaser++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First off, I'm hesitant to just give you the answer in code since this is for a school project and we learn by *challenging* ourselves and *actualizing* solutions. But I'm willing to point you in the right direction.

---

### **1. getHigherLower()**

As others have pointed out, your two while loops are set up to cause errors. For instance, if I first guess too low, and then too high, your method mistakenly tells me I guessed correctly. *This is a big problem!*

> - Random number = **63**
> - Guess 1 = **34** (lower)
> - Guess 2 = **100** (higher)
> - Actually your program tells me my guess of "100" when the number is "63" is correct!

```
// 1st conditional check: 34 !> 63, so skips first while loop
while (guess > randomNumber) {
    guess = getGuess(console);
}

// 1st conditional check: 34 < 63, so enters second while loop
// 2nd conditional check: 100 !< 63, so skips second while loop
while (guess < randomNumber) {

    // guess now becomes 100, goes back to top of while loop to check condition again
    guess = getGuess(console);
}

// returns and exits method here (program wrongly thinks user has guessed correctly!)
```

Note that you can do a

```
System.out.println("random number: " + number);
```

to test that you're actually guessing the random number correctly. You might look into some [JUnit testing](http://junit.org/) as well.

James Ko seems to have a good feel for a [better method implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29957682/4509668).

---

### **2. playAgain()**

You use an if statement to check if the first index in an array of strings equals "y" or "Y" but your program never continues. Why is this?

```
if (yesOrNo[?].equals("y") {
        anotherTime = true;
}
```

You should consider whether user input is really being placed at the first index or not?

*Hint*: loop through the "yesOrNo" array and print out each index to see where the user input is being placed in the array.

```
for (int i = 0; i < yesOrNo.length; i++) {
    System.out.println("String at index " + i + ": " + yesOrNo[i]);
}
```

---

Good luck and remember that testing is your friend!

Comment: You're welcome! If my answer was useful, I'd appreciate an upvote. If it wasn't then I understand completely.

Comment: I would love to upvote your answer and the other answers but I don't have the reputation yet. :(